# Errores con las promesas en angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Los contextualizo, me pidieron mostrar un pdf convertido en base64 por medio un servicio utilizando la libreria ng2-pdf-viewer. (Aclaro que soy programador junior y apenas estoy aprendiendo a utiliza typescript y angular, por lo tanto desconozco los errores y todo comentario que me dejen sera recibido de buena manera para mi aprendizaje)

Lo primero que hice fue declarar la varible de tipo string y dentro de la variable puse el base64, ya con eso cree mi servicio (Esto lo hice dentro de mi servicio llamado DetailService)

```
export class DetailService {

image: string = "aqui va el base64 pero es un codigo muy largo"

    base64ToPdf(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if(this.image){
                resolve(this.image);
            }
            reject("Error not get image")
        });
    }
    
}
```

Luego dentro de mi controlador o componente cree una variable de tipo de string al igual que cree la funcion y despues lo que hice para mostrarla fue inicializar la funcion en el ngOnInit().

```
export class PreviewReportComponent implements OnInit {
    pdfSrc: string;

    constructor(private detailService: DetailService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
          this.base64ToPdf();
    }

    base64ToPdf(){
        this.detailService.base64ToPdf().then((res: string) => {
            this.pdfSrc = res;
        }).catch((err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }


}
```

Ahora por medio de la libreria necesito visualizar el pdf, todo esto dentro del componente.html (De ahi que declaro la variable "pdfSrc" en mi .ts para luego en la parte de la libreria mostrarla en [src])

```
<h2>Integrate PDF File Viewer in Angular</h2>
<pdf-viewer
  [src]="pdfSrc"
  [render-text]="true"
  [original-size]="false"
  style="width: 800px; height: 600px"
></pdf-viewer>
</div>
```

Segun yo todo funciona perfecto, hasta que reviso en consola y me encuentro con estos errores, ¿Cómo y de que manera puedo solucionarlos?, muchas gracias.
[image: Errores angular, programador junior]

Comment: ¿La cadena en base64 la recuperas desde alguna API?

Comment: @Lobos no, en el servicio creo una variable de tipo string ahi coloco el codigo ya en base64

Comment: revisa si no hay error con  la conversión   en base64.No mostras por ser muy largo image como lo formas?.También tener en cuenta que no se permiten preguntas repetidas  formulaste la misma pregunta dos veces

Comment: entiendo que convertiste el pdf a base64 para poder usarlo me parece se debería usar ngx-extended-pdf-viewer    https://pdfviewer.net/extended-pdf-viewer/base64

Comment: @nestdan logre que se mostrara en base64 pero el mismo error me sale aun por consola y tambien utilizo una funcion para decargar el pdf y cuando se sale el file dañado.

Comment: @nestdan gracias por tu ayuda y lamento repetir una pregunta.

Comment: lo intentaste con ` <ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [base64Src]="base"`

Comment: @nestdan efectivamente, ya soluciono todo, igualmente agradezco tus apoyo.